# Extract link from file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to extract an URL from a file. I have the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and I have the extracted the link but the problem is that I also get the information on which line the match is:

```
$txtContent= "C:\xampp\htdocs\test.txt";
$regex = '([a-zA-Z]{3,})://([/^client$/]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)*?'

select-string -Path $txtContent -Pattern $regex -AllMatches  | Select-Object -First 1
```

So I get something like this and I want only the URL:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test.txt:24:                                    http://client.bla:8080/getdata.php
```

So the output should be only this:

```
http://client.bla:8080/getdata.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the `Line`:

```
select-string -Path $txtContent -Pattern $regex -AllMatches  | Select-Object -expand Line -First 1
```